# How to enable and disable div click event on ajax succeed

Tags: jquery

I have four divs on a popup and each click makes a ajax call to the back end and paints the right hand side. All four clicks are div by id clicks. When user clicks on div i want to disable the other three divs till this ajax complete. Once the ajax succeeds i want to enable the click events for the other three divs. Like that i want to do for all four div clicks.

Sometimes the server response is slow and i don't want user to click all of them and show busy indicators for all of them.

Any kind of advice is really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try anything that didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice way I've seen it done, and done it myself is to use a modal 'mask' overlay.

The grayed out transparent mask that covers the entire page, except for the element you're interacting with, eg. modal popup window.

You could do a mini version of it just within the popup and push the three non active divs behind it with CSS z-index.

One more way is to use the [jQuery BlockUI plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/).

Another way, not recommended by jQuery is `async` this will block the browser itself.

```
var html = $.ajax({
  url: "some.php",
  async: false
 }).responseText;
```

jQuery also has `.ajaxStart()` and `.ajaxStop()` events that you can write your loading indicator code into.

Comment: +1 and i forgot in my answer he was talking about divs; a reason why i was using `#field_id` in my example :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use some global `gAjaxInProgress` variable set to `true` when an ajax call is in progress and to `false` when done. In each click function you can then check if an ajax call is in progress and if so return.

Comment: jQuery already has .ajaxStart() and .ajaxStop() events that you can write your loading indicator code into.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I would suggest is to set a meaningless CSS class on the divs, and then have jQuery check if this class is present before executing an AJAX call. Example (untested):

```
$("#divContainer > div").bind('click', function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('disabled-during-ajax'))
        return;
    $("#divContainer > div").addClass('disabled-during-ajax');
    $.get('somefile.php', {}, function(data) {
        $("#divContainer > div").removeClass('disabled-during-ajax');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
//...grab the other divs...

div2.onclick = false;
div3.onclick = false;
div4.onclick = false;

function div2fcn() { alert('div2 activated'); }

//When you're ready:
div2.onclick = div2fcn;
```

Comment: This looks like simple solution , i will try this.